# LARAVEL SAIL: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "composer": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php

I am quite new to Laravel even though I have already created several mini projects.

Today I tried to create a new Laravel project with Sail in the way that the documentation indicates

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/blade-components | bash
```

The application is created correctly, I raise the container with **./vendor/bin/sail up**, I compile the styles with **sail npm run dev**, I run the migrations and everything is correct in the browser (localhost).

The problem comes when trying to install JetStream with the composer command

```
sail composer require laravel/jetstream
```

The error is:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container
> process: exec: "composer": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

For some reason, it's like composer doesn't get installed to the project.

When I run sail, or sail npm (for example), it recognizes the commands and shows me the different actions available. I tried to run the composer command from sail's attach shell and it doesn't recognize it.

```
Executing task: docker exec -it 7b2cd6402559708130d9fdf7b8f8e8cbcd9ed47d524a77dd10cf2ee0068b5150 bash 

root@7b2cd6402559:/var/www/html# composer
bash: composer: command not found
```

Then I opened previous Laravel projects to test if the sail composer command worked and the same thing happens (it didn't before), so it's not a project-specific thing.

I would greatly appreciate your help! P.S.: sorry for my English, greetings from Argentina!

Comment: Before using the composer it needs to be installed. Not having it in $PATH is normally a sign it has not been (properly) installed. So you have a diagnostic message, you own it, docker created it specifically for you!

Comment: Great! I got it, but what can I do? Should I add it to the $PATH? How?

Comment: see `php --help` or [the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) on how you can invoke php scripts of which composer.phar is one.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

My operating system is Windows11 and I created the laravel project in WSL
.

I found that if I `service docker start` in WSL, `sail up -d`  will create or start containers in WSL and `sail composer` will show the same error.

But if I do not `service docker start` in WSL, `sail up -d`  will create or start containers in Windows11 and everything is fine.

p.s. Sorry for my English, too.